# Set font for EPPlus chart elements

Tags: c#, epplus

I want my chart elements to use a specific font family - Quire Sans.

I can set the font for cells and it works fine:

```
ws.Cells[1, 1, 100, 100].Style.Font.Name = "Quire Sans";
ws.Cells[1, 1, 100, 100].Style.Font.Size = 15;
```

However, on a chart, it doesn't work:

```
barChart.XAxis.Font.SetFromFont(new Font("Quire Sans", 18));
```

That line will actually work if I use something like Arial:

```
barChart.XAxis.Font.SetFromFont(new Font("Arial", 18));
```

Why would this work for some fonts, but not others?

Note that for the cells, it's setting an `ExcelFont` property/object, whereas on the chart, it's setting to an `ExcelTextFont` property/object.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to need some combination of the following:

```
barChart.Title.Font.SetFromFont(new Font("Quite Sans", 12));
barChart.Title.Font.ComplexFont = "Quire Sans";
barChart.Title.Font.LatinFont = "Quire Sans";
```